# How to change date/time format Linux gnome?

Tags: linux-mint, gnome, clock

I have installed Gnome on my Linux 18 mint and I see the time at the top says:[image]

Basically it says **Sun May 7, 00:26**, and I would like for it to say **May 7, 2017 | 12:26 AM**. I remember being able to right click and edit the calendar and edit this myself but the option seems gone now.
[image]

How can I change the way the time displays?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about putting in the '|' or removing the day of the week, but if you want to change the format to 12 hour instead of 24 hour, go to Settings > Date & Time. There is a drop-down menu at the bottom, change it from 24-hour to AM / PM.